# How can I prove that $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(1+\cos(\alpha)\cos(x))}{\cos(x)}dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{4}-\alpha^2\right)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> How can I prove that 
>   $$
> \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(1+\cos(\alpha)\cos(x))}{\cos(x)}dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{4}-\alpha^2\right)\,?
> $$

The first thing to try is directly calculating the left hand side. However, I do not know how to find the antiderivative of the integrand: change of variables seems to be rather complicated. How can I go on with this problem.

Comment: I'd suggest expanding the integrand into a power series in $\cos x$.

Comment: Here's a very similar question: [Prove via differentiation that integral $\int_0^\pi \frac{\log(1+\cos\alpha\cos\theta)}{\cos\theta}\,d\theta = \pi(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883882/prove-via-differentiation-that-integral-int-0-pi-frac-log1-cos-alpha-cos)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove via differentiation that integral $\int_0^\pi \frac{\log(1+\cos\alpha\cos\theta)}{\cos\theta}\,d\theta = \pi(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883882/prove-via-differentiation-that-integral-int-0-pi-frac-log1-cos-alpha-cos) (the same approach works)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**

I suppose that the trick is differentiation under the integral sign.

$$g(a)=\int\frac{\ln(1+\cos(a)\cos(x))}{\cos(x)}\,dx$$
$$g'(a)=-\int\frac{\sin (a)}{1+\cos (a) \cos (x)}\,dx$$